# Opentelemetry helm charts could not create replicaset on Kubernetes

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

[image]I want to install opentelemetry-collector on Kubernetes, then installed opentelemetry-collector from [here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/opentelemetry-helm/opentelemetry-collector). I faced there is no replicaset in my pod.

How can i solve this?

I want to connect with my services to opentelemetry-collector.